# How do I disable Excel touch scroll bounce at top of sheet?

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-excel, touchpad, microsoft-excel-2016, scrolling

How can I disable Microsoft Excel's sheet overscroll bounce animation when touchpad scrolling to the top or left of sheet on Windows 10?

You can see what I mean by the video here, https://imgur.com/a/epsgqIV

I have tried setting all Bouncing values (e.g. Software/Microsoft/Wisp/Touch/Bouncing) in the registry to 0.

Answer (score 2):

No soluton.

After we configure Bouncing in "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Wisp\Touch" to 0.

Excel still does it though, but that utterly demented whole-window-overscroll-bullshit is gone, at least.

Also disable hardware graphics acceleration in Excel.
[image]